# Node Express Send Error Pending

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-404, send

I am having a problem sending a '404' response in Express. I have the following code:

```
app.get("/oneimage/:id", function(req, res) {
  Images.findById(req.params.id, function(error, results) {
    if (error) {
        res.json(error, 400);
    } else if (!results) {
         res.send(404, 'No Logo Found ')
    } else {
        res.contentType(results.imageType);
        res.end(results.image.buffer, "binary");
    }
  });
});
```

In the else if, if there are no results the send(404) hangs, I can see that the request remains pending and never times out.

I have tried replacing the send with :

```
  res.wrtieHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.write('Not found!');
  res.end();
```

I am using Chrome Version 30.0.1599.114. I originally thought it might be a Chrome issue, but I see the same behaviour in Firefox.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Should work just fine. Perhaps some middleware that's getting in the way?

Comment: @robertklep thanks, I will investigate further ...

Comment: I'm also having this problem now, have you found any solutions... after 2 years?

Comment: @Denny I really can't remember now :-)